# Prove the function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

Define $f(x)=\begin{cases} x^2 \text{ if } x\le 0 \\ x \text{ if } x>0 \end{cases}$.

Prove the function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

The problem says to use the fact that $f:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $x_0$ if and only if $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f:B\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are continuous at $x_0$ where $A=\{x\in D|x\ge x_0\}$ and $B=\{x\in D|x\le x_0\}$, but I'm not sure how to do this since our $B$ does not include $0$.

Answer (score 7):

You have only to check that $\lim_{x \to 0^{-}} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0^{+}} f(x)$.

Comment: I think I see. So I just have to say that as $\{x_n\}\rightarrow 0$, $\{f(x_n)\}\rightarrow 0$ from both the right and left.

Comment: You must also check if $f(0)=lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x)$ but that part is obvious.

Answer (score 2):

The hint is asking you to use the pasting lemma. $A=\{x\leq 0\}$ and $B=\{x\geq 0\}$ are both closed, $g:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $h:B\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are continuous, $A\cup B=\mathbb{R}$ and $\forall x\in A\cap B$ $g(x)=h(x)$. Then $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as follows:
$$f(x)= \begin{cases}g(x) & x\in A\\ h(x) & x\in B\end{cases}$$
is continuous. In you case, $g$ and $h$ are pretty much suggested. If you want to see the more general version of the pasting lemma, you should visit: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma